# Conditional Expectation of Increasing Function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $g$ be an increasing function and $X$ a normal random variable. Is $p \mapsto \mathbf{E}[g(X)\, | \,X  \le p]$ an increasing function? My intuition says that each 'increment' of p would add more to the running average and so it must be true.

Comment: Yes. $X$ doesn't have to be normal.

Comment: How do I prove this?

Comment: If $q<p$, then $X|X\le p$ is a mixture of $Y_1=X|X\le q$ and $Y_2=X|X\in (q,p]$ and $g(Y_1)\le g(Y_2)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume the expectation exist. For $q > p$,

$$ \begin{align} E[g(X)|X \leq q] 
& = \int_{-\infty}^q g(x)\frac {f_X(x)} {F_X(q)}dx \\ 
& = \frac {F_X(p)} {F_X(q)}\int_{-\infty}^p g(x)\frac {f_X(x)} {F_X(p)}dx + 
\int_p^q g(x)\frac {f_X(x)} {F_X(q)}dx \\
& = E[g(X)|X \leq p] - \left(1 - \frac {F_X(p)} {F_X(q)}\right)\int_{-\infty}^p g(x)\frac {f_X(x)} {F_X(p)}dx + \int_p^q g(x)\frac {f_X(x)} {F_X(q)}dx \\
& \geq E[g(X)|X \leq p] - \left(1 - \frac {F_X(p)} {F_X(q)}\right) g(p)
\int_{-\infty}^p \frac {f_X(x)} {F_X(p)}dx 
+ g(p)\int_p^q \frac {f_X(x)} {F_X(q)}dx \\
& = E[g(X)|X \leq p] - \left(1 - \frac {F_X(p)} {F_X(q)}\right) g(p) 
+ \frac {F_X(q) - F_X(p)} {F_X(q)}g(p) \\
& = E[g(X)|X \leq p]
\end{align}$$

So yes your intuition is correct, it is increasing with $p$.