# Show that conditional expectation is increasing in the conditional

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation, conditional-probability

We have $X_1=a+\epsilon_1$, $X_2=X_1+a+\epsilon_2$, the first two steps of a random walk with drift $a$, where $a$, $\epsilon_1$ and $\epsilon_2$ are independent RVs. I originally am interested in showing that $\mathbb{E}(X_2\mid X_1<x_1,X_2<x_2)$ is increasing in $x_1$ and $x_2$. It is not hard to show that $\mathbb{E}(X_2\mid X_2<x_2)$ is increasing in $x_2$, so one thing I can do is to write

$$\mathbb{E}(X_2\mid X_1<x_1,X_2<x_2)=\mathbb{E}(X_2\mid X_2-a-\epsilon_2<x_1,X_2<x_2)=$$
$$\mathbb{E}(X_2\mid X_2<\min\{x_2,x_1+a+\epsilon_2\})=\mathbb{E}(X_2\mid X_2<x^*(x_1,x_2))$$

for $x^*(x_1,x_2)=\min\{x_2,x_1+a+\epsilon_2\}$, a non decreasing function of $x_1$ and $x_2$, taking me to the case I know how to prove.

I am wondering, however, if in general, we can show that, when $Cov(X_1,X_2)>0$, $\mathbb{E}(X_2\mid X_1<x_1,X_2<x_2)$ is non-decreasing in $x_1$ and $x_2$.

Any thoughts on this? it seems intuitive, but haven't been able to show it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even in your original setting, it is *false* that $E[X_2 \mid X_1 < x_1, X_2 < x_2]$ is non-decreasing in both $x_1, x_2$.

First, here is the counter-example:

- $a = 1$ (constant)
- Bernoulli $\epsilon_1 \in \{0, 10\}$, with probability $1/2$ each.
- Then $X_1 \in \{1, 11\}$ with probability $1/2$ each.
- Bernoulli $\epsilon_2 \in \{0, 100\}$, with probability $1/2$ each.
- Then $X_2 \in \{2, 12, 102, 112\}$ with probability $1/4$ each.
- $E[X_2 \mid X_1 < 5, X_2 < 107] = {2 + 102 \over 2} = 52$
- $E[X_2 \mid X_1 < 1000, X_2 < 107] = {2 + 12 + 102 \over 3} = 38.666... < 52$.

What is wrong with your "proof"?  All your equations about expected values are correct.  However, even for a given $(x_1, x_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2$, the term $x^*(x_1,x_2)=\min\{x_2,x_1+a+\epsilon_2\}$ is not just a real number.  Instead it is a *random variable*, because $a$ and $\epsilon_2$ are both r.v.s.  Therefore when you wrote $E[X_2 \mid X_2 < x^*(x_1,x_2)]$, the conditioning event

$$X_2 < x^*(x_1,x_2)$$

is a comparison between two random variables, $X_2$ and $x^*(x_1,x_2)$.  Therefore, you cannot just invoke your result that $E[X_2 \mid X_2 < x_2]$ is non-decreasing in $x_2$, since that result only works when $x_2$ is a real number.

BTW, the two r.v.s $X_2$ and $x^*(x_1, x_2)$ are also dependent, since both their definitions involve $a$ and $\epsilon_2$.

---

Incidentally, the same counter-example also satisfies $Cov(X_1, X_2) =25 > 0$, thus answering No to your latter question also.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is indeed very enlightening.

Comment: You might also be interested in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3101793/expectation-of-x-given-x-y-a/3105728#3105728) thematically related thread, where I showed that even when for _independent_ r.v.s $X,Y$, you can still have $E[X \mid X > Y + a]$ be decreasing in real variable $a$.

Comment: Thanks! it is really useful, especially because seems counterintuitive at first, but after looking at the examples, it seems that the contribution in growth of the other variable is not enough to overcome the reduction in expectation that comes from considering a broader set of events. I'll look more into it. Z

Comment: @ZekyMurra - I've been thinking more and I think $E[X_2 \mid A, X_2 < x_2]$ is non-decreasing in $x_2$ for any event $A$, regardless of how dependent $A$ and $X_2$ might be.  This is because conditioning on $A$ just sort of makes a new ("smaller") probability space, and in that space, $E[X_2 \mid X_2 < x_2]$ will be true.  So in other words, your original $f(x_1, x_2) = E[X_2 \mid X_1 < x_1, X_2 < x_2]$, viewed as a function $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$, is non-decreasing in $x_2$ (your instinct is correct), but can be decreasing in $x_1$ (as my counter-example showed).

Comment: yes! I think you're right, because the monotonicity of the integral and the fact that we are considering probability measures: When $x_2$ decreases, regardless of the event A, the values of $X_2$ averaged out are smaller, and their weights are all adjusted by the same $\frac{1}{F_{X_2}(x_2)}$. Thanks!